# Not able to see JFrame title bar in Unix

Tags: java, swing, unix

I am running java swing UI code from Unix but is not able to print title bar of frame. Is there any special way Unix treats swing java code? Same code is working fine. please suggest on it

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setTitle("SampleFrame");
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You're recommended to provide runnable source code, otherwise people find it very hard to guess at what could be going wrong. The JVM is intended to be cross-platform which makes it unlikely that the target environment is causing issues, at least within the core Java code spec.

Comment: Using below jdk version
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.3.el5.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? You're setting the title of your `JFrame` twice (`"FrameDemo"` and `"SampleFrame"`) which means only `"SampleFrame"` will be shown, and `frame.getTitle()` will return `"SampleFrame"`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an effect of the particular native window manager. By default Swing windows use native title bars. You can force it to use a look-and-feel specific rendering:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);  // before creating any window
```